# SQl Managment Studio 18 - Blinking Text Cursor hidden in Query

Tags: sql, ssms, ssms-2017

The I-beam has disappeared. It's starting to make it exponentially harder to type not knowing where I am in the query. If someone knows a fix that would be awesome.

Answer (score 8):

I encountered same issue with the OP and my SSMS doesn't have any add-ins and up to date. I have to copy all, open a New Query then paste to solve the issue.

Comment: A bit of a whack but this works! I was assuming I pressed a key and it disappeared. Tried alt key too but nope

Answer (score 5):

Just close the management studio and reopen it.

Comment: I was able to open a new tab and the cursor was back.

Answer (score 1):

You have any add-ins installed? (try disabling them)
Also try to load latest service packs for SSMS/Windows.

Answer (score 1):

You may have hit the <kbd>alt</kbd> key; just pressing <kbd>alt</kbd> brings it back up.

Comment: Please don't vandalise your answers. If you want to delete your answer, delete it using the link next to the edit and share links.

Answer (score 0):

[SSMS Left hand side panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IOhVX.png)

If you see your cursor changing its size and shape when you hover around this yellow line in SSMS, then you probably have clicked while on this yellow line, which changes the cursor type and makes it all weird and vintage. Just go back there and click again, you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

I actually opened a new tab which solved the problem, no need to restart the Application.

Answer (score 0):

Pressed the insert key and it worked. Hope it works for you too!

Answer (score 0):

In the SSMS query, pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd> and <kbd>Insert</kbd> fixed it for me.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. If possible, please 

[edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/78182814/edit)

your post to add further details, such as explanations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information in [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) - *"Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better."*  I suggest reading some highly voted answers for examples.  Thanks!